# Data view on lists not working to specific user

Tags: list, datasheet

On our SharePoint 2010 site, one of the user is having full control but is unable to view **datasheet view** on any of the lists. When she clicks on datasheet view it is showing empty, and doesn't show the previous data as well. What would be the resolution for this?

[image]